# Regular expression for Number masking with exceptions

Tags: regex

I want to mask phone numbers in a resume which also contains date in the for `2001, 2001-03` and percentages `45% 87% 78.45% 56.5%`.

I only want to mask the phone numbers, and I don't need to mask it completely. If I could  only mask 3 or 4 digits that makes it hard to guess, that does the job.  Kindly help me out.

```
Phone number formats are 
9876543210
98765 43210
98765-43210
9876 543 210
9876-543-210
```

Comment: How long are the phone numbers? 10 digits? Any specifics?

Comment: Yes ten digits, but in different formats as mentioned.

Comment: 9876543210,  98765 43210,  98765-43210,  9876 543 210,  9876-543-210

Comment: Javascript, Notepad++, Java, PCRE? What would you use the regex with?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer:

```
 (([0-9][- ]*){5})(([0-9][- ]*){5})
```

It will match exactly 10 digits with or without `-` or space.

After that, you can replace the first or the third group with `*****` or anything you like.

For example:

```
$1*****
```

Answer (score 1):

`\d{4,5}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{2,3}`

**Strings matched:**

> `9876543210, 98765 43210, 98765-43210, 9876 543 210, 9876-543-210`

**Strings not matched:**

> ```
> 45% 87% 78.45% 56.5%
> 2001, 2001-03
> ```

I feel that a more complicated regex that *doesn't* match invalid phone numbers is not required since the requirement is to mask valid phone numbers of the above format.

Check [here](http://regexr.com/3dodn)

**Python code:**

```
def fun(m):
  if m:
    return '*'*len(m.group(1))+m.group(2)

string = "Resume of candidate abcd. His phone numbers are : 9876543210, 98765 43210, 98765-43210.Date of birth of the candidate is 23-10-2013. His percentage is 57%. One more number 9876 543 213 His percentage in grad school is 44%. Another number  9876-543-210"

re.sub('(\d{4,5})([ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{2,3})',fun,string)
```

**Output:**

```
'Resume of candidate abcd. His phone numbers are : *****43210, *****
43210, *****-43210. Date of birth of the candidate is 23-10-2013. His
percentage is 57%. One more number **** 543 213 His percentage in grad
school is 44%. Another number  ****-543-210'
```

**More about re.sub:**

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
> occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the
> pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a
> string or a function;

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you on your way... I would use python to do is.
Use `re` module to search for number-like strings:

```
import re
num_re = re.compile('[0-9 -]{5,}')
with open('/my/file', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        for s in num_re.findall(l):
            # Do some addition testing, like 'not starting with' or any
            l.replace(s, '!!!MASKED!!!')
        print l
```

I'm not saying that this code is finished, but it should help you on your way.

By the way, why I would use this approach:

- You can easily add any tests you like to fix false positives.
- Its readable.